# How to post data using Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

i am unable to get posted data on sever using php it returns

Output : Array()

Php Code

```
public function create()
    {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
```

Angular Code

```
angular.module('index',[])
    .controller('SignUpController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

      $scope.signup=function(user){
        var dataObj = {
                "name" : "sdadas",
                "employees" : "sadsad",
                "headoffice" : "sadsa"
        };

        $http.post("<?=base_url()."index.php/users/create" ?>",dataObj).
        success(function(data,status,header,config){
            alert(data);
        }).
        error(function(data,status,header,config){

        });
      };

    }]);
```

Comment: What is this actually "<?=base_url()." ???

Comment: base_url()=http://localhost/folderName

Comment: I think you are mixing php inside angular client ?

Comment: <?= is the php echo symbol. You cannot use it inside Angular

Comment: boy its not an problem it ll be eliminated when it comes to client end !

Comment: Try this $http.post("http://localhost/foldername/index.php/users/create",dataObj)

Comment: The problem is when i post data request goes to the destination URL but data i posted never reach there :( i got empty POST array

Comment: @BKM i have no syntax error in my code there is some logical error !

Comment: @QasimKhokhar: I hope you meant 'but', not 'boy'. Otherwise it looks rude to ask a question and then to insult people that are trying to help you. Show some respect or GTFO.

Comment: Try sending JSON.stringify(dataObj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function create()
{
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what base url is but i guess it's a function so i rewrote it from this

```
$http.post("<?=base_url()."index.php/users/create" ?>",dataObj).
    success(function(data,status,header,config){
        alert(data);
    }).
```

To this u should put it between single quotes

```
    $http.post('<? echo base_url()."index.php/users/create"; ?>',dataObj).
    success(function(data,status,header,config){
        alert(data);
    }).
```